# Invoke-Command returning data

Tags: powershell, remoting, invoke-command

I am working on a script to query remote servers for configuration information and return the data for output to gridview.  The issue I am having is the format in which the data is returned.

If I do...

```
((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Measure-Object).Count
((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory).Capacity | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum /1GB
```

in a ps1 and run that on a remote server using Invoke-Command, I get an array back with only numbers like this.

```
2
4
```

How can I gather this information with context from multiple machines efficiently?  I tried remote jobs, but I can't really run more than 2 jobs at a time.  I would like to spread out the work to all of the target servers like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values actually have the computer name e.g.:

```
30# $r = Invoke-Command ...
31# $r[0]
4
32# $r[0].PSComputerName
hillr2
```

PowerShell just doesn't display that info by default for number.  You could do this:

```
32# icm hillr2 -ScriptBlock {
>>> $NumLogCpu = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
>>> $MemSize = ((Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory).Capacity | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum /1GB
>>> [pscustomobject]@{NumLogCpu=$NumLogCpu;MemSize=$MemSize}
>>> }


NumLogCpu      : 4
MemSize        : 8.00390625
PSComputerName : hillr2
RunspaceId     : fb03fedd-2771-46cf-916a-f31ec7c8298b
```

This requires PowerShell v3 or higher for the [pscustomobject] type accelerator.

Comment: OK nice, I hadn't thought of that.  I tried the psobject route, but the issue I have though is getting the information (psobject) back from the script.  So I run the script using 
    $x = Invoke-Command .\script.ps1 
and I can recover the data from the queries using $x (array of "2" and "4") but I can't seem to get the psobject itself back.  Do I need to return it?

Comment: I would love to get [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName=$CompNm;NumLogCpu=$NumLogCpu;MemSize=$MemSize} back as an object so I can "stack" them up for gridview.

Comment: Never mind, I just got it.  I needed to assign a variable to the pscustomobject and repeat it at the end of the script to get it back as $x.