# Listing computer name with result in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that returns the registry key, however the result doesn't show the computer that is returning the key.

How could I modify this code so it will list the computer and key.

```
$key={(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -Name Release).Release}
$computers = @(Get-Content computers.txt)
foreach ($computer in $computers){ 
Invoke-Command -computer $computer -scriptblock $key >> version.csv}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664595/invoke-command-returning-data ??

Comment: @ErikE The solution you linked says that it requires PS v3 I am running v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should do what you need:

```
$key={(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -Name Release).Release}
$computers = @(Get-Content computer.txt)

foreach ($computer in $computers){    
    $result = Invoke-Command -computer $computer -scriptblock $key
    $FinalStr = "$($Computer) : $($result)"
   $FinalStr >> version.csv    
}
```

Comment: That was the ticket.  Thank you very much @Arcass.